# How to call REST service by setting Matrix Params using Camel-Http4 component?

Tags: rest, apache-camel

I have a problem trying to use Camel-http4 component. What I want to do is to set from my camel route the Matrix Params that the REST service needs to work properly. Is there any way to do that?

Thank you,
Roxana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using traditional query parameters, the Camel URI looks as follows:

```
from("direct:start")
    .to("http4://oldhost?order=123&detail=short");
```

Thus, using matrix parameters should work as well:

```
from("direct:start")
    .to("http4://oldhost;order=123;detail=short");
```

**Edit:**

Use `Exchange.HTTP_URI` for dynamically setting the properties or use `recipientList` such as:

```
from("direct:start")
    .recipientList(simple("http4://oldhost;order=${header.123Header};detail={{value.from.cfg}}"));
```

Comment: I solved the problem in some other way. What I wanted was to read from a .cfg the values for my Matrix Params or to take those walues from some headers. I wasn't able to do something like: to("http4://oldhost;order=${headers.123Header};detail={{value.from.cfg}}"). In order to make this possible I used the Exchange.HTTP_URI header which will replace my actual rest endpoint withe value I specify there. Is not a clean solution :( but it works. I expected camel to have a header for matrix params similar with the one for query params. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @Roxana Alternatively you may use `recipientList`, see my answer how this can be done.